# Keep getting an error "does not contain a method named 'Trim'. when using a simple Trim command- what is wrong with my code?

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell - sorry if this is something simple - I just cannot get past this problem.

I am looking for a way to strip out a particular segment from a .txt file.  The file contains a section I need to save to an output file. and then run that output file through the window decode utility; But I keep getting an error when I try to trim characters out of it.

The file is a HL7 flat text file that has a OBX segments that begins ^Base64^ and then ends with a | (pipe)

I want to be able to strip that part and save to another file so I can UN-encode it from the Base64 format using windows command.

The text file contains: "MSH|^~&|FUNNET|PA|4273||202006231608||ORU^R01|68328535M14273|P|2.5.1||||||||
PID||400659^^^Enterprise ID|400659^^^Enterprise ID|400659|DOG^SNOOPY||19371225|M||2|610 GREEN RED BLUE DR
PV1||O|!12345||||1124082128^DRT^|^^^|||||||||^^NHAN^|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
ORC|RE|15089553H14273||||||||||1124082128^DR^T||||||||||||
OBR|1|15089553H14273||392334^ELECTROCARDIOGRAM|2|20200623154728||||||||||1124082128^NDR^T||||||||F||||||||||||||||||||
OBX|1|ED|||^^PDF^Base64^JVBERi0xLjMNJf////8NMSAwIG9iag08PA0vVGl0bGUgKP7/AE0AaQBkAG0AYQByAGsAIABEAGkAYQBnAG4AbwBzAHQAaQBjAeHJlZg04NTY2OTENJSVFT0YN|||||||||20200623154728|||"

I used the following to grab the area I need but cannot get it to exclude the extra ^ and it only recognizes the Base64 in Regex and not the ^Base64^ in Regex; so I thought to trim at this point but I now get a error when trying to use the Trim command.

Method invocation failed because [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match] does not contain a method named 'Trim'.
At C:\Users\sschmit1\Desktop\Pull_Base64.ps1:8 char:1

- $Pass2 = $Pass1.Trim("^","|")
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
  ```

Code used:

$RawData = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Sschmit1\temp\Test_ORU\ORU_test.txt  | Select-String "Base64"
$Regex = [Regex]::new("(?<=Base64)(.*)(?=2020)")
$Pass1 = $Regex.Match($RawData)

$Pass1    #output by getting file

$Pass2 = $Pass1.Trim("^","|")
$Pass2    #output after finshed trimming

Thank you - mr. newbie

Comment: After 4 years on SO, mind using the appropriate [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)? I would like to help, but your post is so hard to read...

Answer (score 1):

since you didn't format the code in a readable manner, i can't figure out where your error is. [*sigh ...*]

instead, here's another way to do the job ... [*grin*]

what it does ...

- sets the prefix and suffix strings
  these provide the boundaries of the target data.
- saves the sample line into `$InStuff`
- applies a regex escape to the `$Prefix` since it contains special regex chars
  the `-split` operator is a regex operator, so the `^` needs to be escaped.
- splits on the escaped `$Prefix`
- takes the last part of that split
- splits on the `$Suffix`
  since this uses the `.Split()` method, no regex escape is needed.
- takes the 1st part of that split
- joins the `$Prefix` and the result of the above splits
- saves it to `$OutStuff`
- displays that on screen

the code ...

```
$Prefix = '^base64'
$Suffix = '|'

$InStuff = "MSH|^~&|FUNNET|PA|4273||202006231608||ORU^R01|68328535M14273|P|2.5.1|||||||| PID||400659^^^Enterprise ID|400659^^^Enterprise ID|400659|DOG^SNOOPY||19371225|M||2|610 GREEN RED BLUE DR PV1||O|!12345||||1124082128^DRT^|^^^|||||||||^^NHAN^||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| ORC|RE|15089553H14273||||||||||1124082128^DR^T|||||||||||| OBR|1|15089553H14273||392334^ELECTROCARDIOGRAM|2|20200623154728||||||||||1124082128^NDR^T||||||||F|||||||||||||||||||| OBX|1|ED|||^^PDF^Base64^JVBERi0xLjMNJf////8NMSAwIG9iag08PA0vVGl0bGUgKP7/AE0AaQBkAG0AYQByAGsAIABEAGkAYQBnAG4AbwBzAHQAaQBjAeHJlZg04NTY2OTENJSVFT0YN|||||||||20200623154728|||"

$OutStuff = -join ($Prefix, ($InStuff -split [regex]::Escape($Prefix))[-1].Split($Suffix)[0])

$OutStuff
```

output ...

```
^base64^JVBERi0xLjMNJf////8NMSAwIG9iag08PA0vVGl0bGUgKP7/AE0AaQBkAG0AYQByAGsAIABEAGkAYQBnAG4AbwBzAHQAaQBjAeHJlZg04NTY2OTENJSVFT0YN
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert $pass 1 to string then do it: (Also you need to get only the value of match)

```
$RawData = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Sschmit1\temp\Test_ORU\ORU_test.txt | Select-String "Base64"
$Regex = [Regex]::new("(?<=Base64)(.*)(?=2020)") 
$Pass1 = $Regex.Match($RawData).Value
$Pass2 = $Pass1.ToString().Trim("^","|")
```

Comment: The ```Value``` property of a ```System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match``` is already a string, so you don't need to call ```ToString()``` on the last line...

Comment: Then it also extracts the regex match value

Comment: Not sure quite what you mean. If I do ```$Regex.Match($RawData).Value.GetType().FullName``` I get ```System.String```, and calling ```ToString()``` on a ```String``` just returns the same value as the original string.